# HTML table with border

Tags: html

Sorry if my question is not clear.
if i create a normal table in HTML, there will be a line below the wording "DAY".

I would like to create the same table, but would like to have no line below the wording "DAY"

I hope i am clear enough.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use rowspan to do that.

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }

table,th,td{
  border:1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">day</td>
    <td>Mon</td>
    <td>Tue</td>
    <td>wed</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
   
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    </tr>
 <table>
```